# Testing connections with custom drivers not supported (Salesforce JDBC)

Tags: jdbc, salesforce, aws-glue, cdata

I'm encountering an issue while trying to set up a custom JDBC connection in AWS Glue for a Salesforce driver using the CData JDBC trial JAR stored in S3 bucket. The goal is to connect to Salesforce using the following configuration:

**JDBC URL:**

```
jdbc:cdata:salesforce:AuthScheme=Basic;User=my_sf_user;Password=my_sf_password;Security Token=my_sf_token;UseSandbox=true;
```

**JDBC Driver Class:**

```
cdata.jdbc.salesforce.SalesforceDriver
```

I've downloaded the JDBC trial JAR from [CData Salesforce JDBC Trial](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/salesforce/jdbc/).

**Error Message:**

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.glue.jobexecutor.commands.exception.CommandExecutorException: com.amazonaws.services.glue.exceptions.InvalidInputException: Testing connections with custom drivers is not currently supported.
```

**Context:**

I'm trying to create a custom JDBC connection in the AWS Glue Console, and want to send the transformed dataset directly to Salesforce object. During the testing phase, I encounter the mentioned error. I suspect this is related to the fact that AWS Glue does not currently support testing connections with custom drivers.

**Steps Taken:**

- Created a custom connection in AWS Glue Console.
- Provided the necessary JDBC URL and Driver Class.
- Downloaded the CData Salesforce JDBC trial JAR stored in S3 bucket.
- Encountered the error during the testing phase.

**Questions:**

- Is testing connections with custom drivers not supported in AWS Glue?
- Is there a workaround or alternative approach for testing connections in this scenario?
- Any insights or recommendations on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is testing connections with custom drivers not supported in AWS Glue?

  - No, testing custom connections is not supported yet: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-test-connections.html
- Is there a workaround or alternative approach for testing connections in this scenario?

  - You could simply run a test ETL job and rely on the logs of the job for testing the connectivity.
- Any insights or recommendations on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

  - There is already a feature request in place for this, so if you have an account manager I would suggest requesting them to +1 the feature request for you.